# Relative links not working after deploying website on server

Tags: html

I have a site in which **hrefs** in anchor tag work perfectly when running file locally but when I **deploy** it on an *Apache* server the **href** link is appended in the address bar but it does not redirect to that link. If I click on the address bar and press enter it then loads that link which means that the file is present and the **href** link is correct.

For example:

`<a href="/login_form.html" class="link external"><div class="menu-icon icon-theme"></div>Login</a>`

is my anchor tag.

Now when I click on this anchor the address bar would change from lets say,

`siteurl.com/dir/` (is on the index.html page) to `siteurl.com/dir/login_form.html`

but it does not load that login page and only if I press f5/reload or enter in the address bar it goes to that page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried validating your html and looking for any JS that could mess with your links?

Comment: But then why is everything working fine when running locally?

Comment: It was a JS file messing up. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If all your pages are on root folder don't use `/` *(slash)* or any folder name. Just mention direct page name with extention like this

```html
<a href="login_form.html">login</a>
```

Comment: Removing the slash makes the link:

```stieurl.com/dir/dir/login_form.html```

The link in the href is fine and works if I load it through the address bar

Answer (score 0):

If the login is in a folder say auth, then the code will be `<a href="root/auth/login">Login</a>`

The format should be `path to login form from root`.